Let $R$ be an associative ring with 1. Let $M$ be a product if infinitely many copies of $R$, viewed as a left $R$-module. Is $M$ locally free?
Let $R$ be an associative ring with 1. Let $M$ be a product if infinitely many copies of $R$, viewed as a left $R$-module. Is $M$ locally free? More precisely: is it true that every finitely generated submodule of $M$ is contained in a free submodule?

No.
Let $R$ be the ring of eventually constant sequences of integers, and let $e_i\in R$ be the sequence whose $i^{th}$ term is 1, with all other terms zero.
Then if $I$ is the annihilator of an element of a free $R$-module, either

there is some $N$ so that $e_i\in I$ for all $i>N$, or
there is some $N$ so that $e_i\not\in I$ for all $i>N$.

But the element $x=(e_1,e_3, e_5, \dots)$ of the countable product of copies of $R$ is annihilated by $e_{2i}$ but not by $e_{2i+1}$ for every $i$, and so the submodule generated by $x$ cannot be a submodule of a free module.

I don't agree that every element of $R$ is annihilated by $e_1-e_{i+!}$ for sufficiently large $i$.

@PeterKropholler You make a good point! I think the example does work, but of course my justification is nonsense. I’ll delete the answer in a while if I don’t manage to fix it quickly.

@PeterKropholler I think (or at least hope!) that I’ve edited my answer so that it is correct.

A relevant paper of Faith.

Yes I believe your answer. Clearly some condition would be required on R. I wonder if products of free modules are locally free for Noetherian rings?

@PeterKropholler In the paper of Faith that I linked to in a previous comment, he considers the following property (“FGTF”) of a ring $R$: every finitely generated submodule of a product of copies of $R$ embeds in a free module. This seems weaker than the property you want, but related. In the introduction, it is claimed that every left Noetherian ring is right FGTF, so maybe being Noetherian on the other side will be the relevant condition.
